# Rotating logs with different names with logrotate

Tags: ubuntu, log-rotation

The logs name are appended with timestamp when generated like log-20140526-062503.txt Is there a way to manage this? I tried with a custom state file but log rotate does not delete old file.

```
/var/logs/*.txt {
rotate 15
daily
compress
missingok
nocreate
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `logrotate` will consider every new logfile with this custom name to be a separate entity to rotate (just like `access_log` and `error_log` would be handled separately if the file pattern would be `/var/log/httpd/*log`). Thus, you will never get to 15 items to rotate.

One way around this might be with the `maxage` option:

> maxage count
>
> Remove  rotated logs older than  days. The age is only checked if the logfile is to be rotated. The files
>                 are mailed to the configured address if maillast and mail are configured.

but I am not sure if this really works.

If this doesn't work I would simply recommend to use a cron job that delete files older than 15 days matching your wildcard, as it appears that your app already uses a new log file every day.